# I have a question about Fourier Series, Does Fourier coefficients depends on interval of integration?

Tags: real-analysis

Does $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t) \sin(nt)dt$, is equal to $\int_0^{2\pi} f(t) \sin(nt)dt$? when I want to know Fourier coefficients from $f(x)$

Comment: If your function is $2\pi$ periodic they are the same.

Comment: @MrYouMath ... and if not then these integrals have no connection to the fourier transform of $f$.

Comment: Fourier transform is not the same as Fourier series.